# FFT of logarithmic input data

Tags: floating-point, numerical-algorithms, fast-fourier-transform

Is there a reasonably accurate method of computing an FFT of logarithmically-represented input data (with a sign bit, that is $±2^{\text{double-precision value}}$)?

The naive method (convert to linear representation, do an ordinary FFT, and convert back to logarithmic representation) very quickly runs into overflow/underflow issues.

Normalizing, by 'dividing' (subtraction in log-representation) the input by the largest absolute value beforehand<sup>1</sup> and restoring at the end helps somewhat, but still suffers from accuracy issues in some cases. Consider e.g. $[C, -C, 1, 0]$ where $C$ is, say, $2^{2^{100}}$. Your constant output term 'should' be $1$, but ends up as $0$, because when normalized the third input term is $\frac{1}{C}=\frac{1}{2^{2^{100}}}=2^{-2^{100}}$, which underflows double precision and is rounded to $0$.

<sup>1</sup>: Or, more likely, normalizing such that the largest input's absolute value is `double.MAX_VAL` instead of `1`.

Comment: It sounds hard, as FFT involves doing both addition/subtraction and multiplication, and addition/subtraction is poorly behaved for logarithmic representation whenever there is any kind of cancellation.

Comment: Indeed. Doing accurate summation of logarithmic-representation values is tricky but doable. Trying to combine that with a FFT... well, if the problem was easy I wouldn't be asking it :-)

Comment: What is the range of your DP values ?

Comment: Like @YvesDaoust says, if the range is small you could calculate each bit "combination", or power of 2, separately.  If it is moderately sized, maybe you could combine a few bits together, and this would create a few combinations, but not a lot.

Comment: @MattGroff: I didn't say anything.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Sorry, I meant that you were asking the range of the values, which I thought was a very good question.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am asking.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I've found out that this scheme is untenable *regardless*. The point of a log-represented input is to handle high dynamic range - but consider the following input:

$$
[2^{-(2^{1000})}, 0, 2^{(2^{1000})}, 0]
$$

An exact DFT would produce the following output:

$$
[2^{-(2^{1000})} + 2^{(2^{1000})}, 2^{-(2^{1000})} - 2^{(2^{1000})}, 2^{-(2^{1000})} + 2^{(2^{1000})}, 2^{-(2^{1000})} - 2^{(2^{1000})}]
$$

Unfortunately, in log-rep none of these are distinguishable from $\pm 2^{(2^{1000})}$. So you end up - even if correctly rounded - with an fft output of

$$
[2^{(2^{1000})}, -(2^{(2^{1000})}), 2^{(2^{1000})},  -(2^{(2^{1000})})]
$$

...which when inverted becomes

$$
[0, 0, 2^{(2^{1000})}, 0]
$$

...rather defeating the point of the extended dynamic range.